# Simple usage of Linear mixed effect model

Tags: mixed-model, spss

have the survey score for many patients for 4 intervals. I wanted to see if there is significant change as time progresses (i.e. interval number goes from 1 to 4). I tried Repeated measures ANOVA, but there was insufficient data with missing values so this led to results with low Power. I researched and found out a linear mixed effect model might be better. So if I have data like the following:

Patient 1

4 , 5 , 6 , 7

i.e. for each patient, just one score for each interval, how do i use linear mixed effect model here? I have researched a lot but cant understand how to use fixed or random effect here. Please can someone just help me understand? Thanks!

P.S. - Here is the result without any random effect added to the model:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time would be a fixed effect and person would be a random effect.

If the patients were not examined at exactly the same intervals, you might want to use a quantitative variable for time (e.g. "days since beginning of study").  You might also want to add covariates.

You may also want to explore various covariance patterns such as AR1, unstructured or compound symmetry.

Comment: Thanks! the scores are sorted into intervals based on date of submission. Can i still go ahead with this model if i do not understand what covariance patterns etc. mean? I have to submit the analysis on monday, so not much time, thanks so much!

Comment: Well .... Since it's due on Monday, I guess you have no choice.

Comment: Hi, for the linear mixed model, If the patient id is in the "Subjects" field in SPSS, do I really have to include it as a random effect as well? I have gotten the following summarized result without including any random effect: (image of the result pasted in updated question)

Comment: So it shows intervals as having a significant influence (based on that table i pasted), i do not understand why i have to include person as a random effect. I am following this youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=otv-EX1Y0M0&t=582s. Here the demonstrator also did not use any random effect.

Comment: You have to include person as a random effect because people are examined multiple times and this violates the assumption of independent errors.